# Problems Reading File

Tags: vb.net

Currently having issues reading data from a file, and assigning it to the text-boxes on my form. The code runs without throwing an error, but no data/values are passed to the text-boxes and they remain blank. Below is my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class ReadingEmployeeData
    ' Declare filename
    Dim FileName As String
    Private Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click
        ' Constant for holding the number of fields
        Const NumFields As Integer = 8

        ' Declare variables
        Dim FileStream As StreamReader
        Dim Count As Integer


        Try
            ' Open file
            FileStream = File.OpenText(FileName)

            ' Read the data
            For Count = 1 To NumFields
                FirstText.Text = FileStream.ReadLine()
                MiddleText.Text = FileStream.ReadLine()
                LastText.Text = FileStream.ReadLine()
                NumberText.Text = FileStream.ReadLine()
                DepartmentText.Text = FileStream.ReadLine()
                PhoneText.Text = FileStream.ReadLine()
                ExtText.Text = FileStream.ReadLine()
                EmailText.Text = FileStream.ReadLine()

            Next Count

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("That file can not be opened.")
        Finally
            FileStream.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadingEmployeeData_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Get the filename from user
        FileName = InputBox("Please enter the name of the file")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: show a simple of text file data?

Comment: Try with only `Dim FileStream As StreamReader(FileName)` and remove that `FileStream = File.OpenText(FileName)` **update** better looking Your code, you try to read 64 "rows" from text file?

Comment: This is a debugging issue.  If there are 10 employees, only the last one will show.  I suspect that based on the button name you want to skip some lines each time.  **Much** better to read the whole file (`File.ReadAllLines()`) and update the UI from there,

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Io.StreamReader`, And there is no need to `NumFields`:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class ReadingEmployeeData
    ' Declare filename
    Dim FileName As String
    Private Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click


        ' Declare variables
        Dim FileStream As StreamReader
        Dim Count As Integer


        Try
            ' Open file
            Using sr As New Io.StreamReader(FileName)

            ' Read the data

                FirstText.Text = sr.ReadLine()
                MiddleText.Text = sr.ReadLine()
                LastText.Text = sr.ReadLine()
                NumberText.Text = sr.ReadLine()
                DepartmentText.Text = sr.ReadLine()
                PhoneText.Text = sr.ReadLine()
                ExtText.Text = sr.ReadLine()
                EmailText.Text = sr.ReadLine()

                sr.Close()

            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception

           MessageBox.Show("That file can not be opened.")

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadingEmployeeData_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Get the filename from user
        FileName = InputBox("Please enter the name of the file")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```